# python extracting date

Tags: python, regex, image-extraction

I need to extract a date from a jpeg format,
I have extracted the text from the jpeg in the form of a string & have used regex to extract the date,

## Text from JPEG

Cont:7225811153;
BillNo4896TableNoR306
07-Jun-201921:18:40

*Code used*

## Importing regular expression & Date time

```
import re as r

from datetime import datetime
```

## regex to identify the date in the above string

```
id = r.search(r'\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}',text)
print(id)
```

*Output*
**re.Match object; span=(89, 100), match='07-Jun-2019'**

However after performing the above code i tried the following to extract the date

Code

## Extracting the date

```
date = datetime.strptime(id.group(),'%d-%B-%Y').date()
```

*Output*

**ValueError: time data '07-Jun-2019' does not match format '%d-%B-%Y'**

Where am I going wrong, or is there a better way to do the same.
Help would be really appreciated

Comment: Try with `%d-%b-%Y`. `%B` is for "Month as locale’s full name" where as `%b` is for "Month as locale’s abbreviated name." [See Documentation for more info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Answer (score 1):

Use `%b` instead of `%B`, but make sure you only try to convert the match *if* it occurred:

```
import re as r
from datetime import datetime
text = 'Cont:7225811153; BillNo4896TableNoR306 07-Jun-201921:18:40'
id = r.search(r'\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}',text)
if id:  # <-- Check if a match occurred
    print(datetime.strptime(id.group(),'%d-%b-%Y').date())
# => 2019-06-07
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/JNveAh)

See more details on the [`datetime.strptime` format strings](https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime).

Answer (score 0):

You had it almost perfect. Just replace the B with b.

```
>>> datetime.strptime(id.group(),'%d-%b-%Y').date()
datetime.date(2019, 6, 7)
```